# Networkdays in VBA for a range of dates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run some code in VBA that checks two column full of start dates and end dates and fills in a 3rd column with the corresponding workdays between the dates.

```
For i = 2 To N
Cells(i, F) = Application.networkdays(C, D)

Next i
```

Above is what I have tried already. I cant show what N is in this case but its basically a function that finds the end of the imported data (that all works). I get Application defined error. If I remove Application. it says networkdays is not a defined sub or function.

```
For i = 2 To 50
Cells(i, "F") = Application.networkdays("C", "D")
Next i
```

If I run the above it populates a 3rd column with #VALUE (50 being an example for N)

```
For i = 2 To 50
Cells(i, "F") = Application.networkdays(C, D)
Next i
```

If I run the above I get the column full of 0.

How can i get this to work? It seems so simple yet VBA seems to be programmed to make EVERYTHING impossible! Same issue on Excel 2013, 2010 and 2016

Answer (score 2):

You need to go row by row in the formula.

```
Cells(i, "F") = Application.networkdays(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "D"))
```

Comment: I wasted 2 hours at work trying to get that working and at one point tried exactly what you just put and it didn't work >.< I must have miss typed somewhere, maybe cell not cells because now it works. Thanks for your help and no doubt the second I come to the next stage of manipulating the data tomorrow, I'll be back!